# font size expressed with divisor?

Tags: css

Today I came accross the following css snippet:

```
#navigation {
    font: bold 12px/18px "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I can't find information about this in the [font-size section](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) of the MDN.

Could anyone give me a quick explanation of how it works?

Comment: Use the source ([spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/fonts.html#font-shorthand)), Luke :)

Comment: oooooh right, line-height!! http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font my bad

Comment: It is not `font-size`, [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/font) property is a shorthand of a dozen font-related properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how that is interpreted:

```
#navigation {
    font: weight size/line-height family;
}
```

[Look here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CSS spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/fonts.html#font-shorthand), the values around the `/` token are `font-size` on the left, and `line-height` on the right. The `/line-height` section is optional.